# How to make EF Migrations work empty AND existing database as starting point?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx) you have two options to add an initial Migration for code-based Migrations in EF:

1. Use an exinsting Database (`Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges`).
   You should use this approach when other databases that migrations will be applied to in the future will have the same schema as your local database currently has.
2. Use an empty Database (`Add-Migration InitialCreate`).
   You should use this approach when other databases that migrations will be applied to in the future are empty (or do not exist yet).

We are trying to switch form automatic migrations to code-based migrations and we need to make both options happen, because (1.) we have an application already installed and running at a customer place and (2.) we want to install more applications fresh.

*How can we achieve this?*

I have two ideas how to realize this, but no clue about side effects or trouble I might run into.

- Use the empty database approach (2.) and manually add code to the `Up()` checking if tables and field exists already in order to skip existing migrations.
- Use the empty database approach (2.) and copy the entries of the __MigrationHistory table manually into our customer's database in order to pretend that they "migrated already".

Side note: We used the existing database approach (1.) to migration the installed application successfully, as exampled in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49211196/how-to-switch-from-ef-automatic-migrations-to-code-based-migrations). Obviously, fresh installations don't work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already used the existing database approach to migrate the installed application successfully then that database will have an entry in the `__MigrationHistory` table with a `migrationid` that matches the filename of the initial migration, and any code that you now place in the `Up` method will not run.
Unfortunately you can't force a re-scaffold of the initial migration for new applications, so here is what I would do:

1. Delete the entry in the __Migrations table
2. Delete your Initial migration
3. `Add-Migration InitialCreate` to scaffold the code required to create your database
4. Comment out the code in the `Up` method, or just add a `return` at the top to prevent it executing.
5. Apply the migration to your existing database.
6. Uncomment the code in the `Up` method so that it executes for future new application

Comment: I see and there is no way to check in the database if those tables are already present, because the `Up()` Method is called when creating the first DbContext. I guess we will create a flag in a config file that says "fresh install = true/false" to check the `Up()` Method should be run or not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The presence of a `migrationid` that matches the filename of the initial migration will prevent the `Up` method being run, so I would run it with code commented out on existing databases, then uncomment the code. No need for a config setting

Comment: but how would run/install an application with (and afterwards without!) code that is commented out? There is no compiler. You would create 2 different installers and run each of them? I guess we could create a Version X (= Code commented out) and have that running until we reach any future Version Y (= Code commented in). X ensures that the `migrationid` is inserted and does not really care if the code is commented in or out afterwards. Later, Y can be installed assuming the id already there. Do you understand my confusion?

Comment: I was assuming that you can ensure that the initial migration has been run on all existing databases before you uncomment the code for new installations

Comment: Great advice. By disabling Up method the __Migrations table was finally added to the existing DB without error.  Then we were in sync again and all was good. Re-enabled Up method.